# Cryptoissues? (stocks & bonds)

Tags: alternatives, future-proof, transaction-verification, stocks

Are there any examples of cryptoequities or cryptoliabilities?

I've seen the [cryptostocks site](https://cryptostocks.com/), but it doesn't look to be what I'm envisioning.

For simplicity's stake, please imagine a corporation that wants to issue stock that will never pay a dividend.

Could a fully integrated trading system be built off of the cryptocurrency concept?

Here are some of the criteria:

- A corporation is the only issuer in a blockchain, so no mining rewards, only fees
- The blockchain would probably need to be denominated in a single cryptocurrency
- There would need to be some sort of automatically resolving escrow system where a buyer first deposits cash through into the blockchain before a trade can go through with automatic refunds if the trade fails
- Buyer and seller would both have to sign the transaction, buyer pledging an amount of cryptocurrency, seller pledging an amount of cryptoequity
- Orders would have to be able to be left in an "open" state to provide a limit book; in other words, buyers would need to be able to post how much cryptocurrency they would want to sell so to buy some amount of cryptoequity while whether the transaction will complete is uncertain, and sellers would need to be able to do the reverse while of course pre-depositing in the escrow
- Open orders would need some mechanism to be canceled
- Orders would need to be able to be partially filled, so an open bid could be partially filled by a seller leaving behind the remaining order and vice versa

How could this be accomplished?

(I will post any other necessary details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple that may be what your looking for.....

Open Transactions - http://opentransactions.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page
This is more general and not specifically targeted at Cryptocurrency, it seems pretty malleable and could be used for what you are describing.

https://counterparty.co/ - This is similar to above, and as I have only just recently found it cant say much, but also looks to do the job.